# Parsing left-recursive grammar in sum-type inifinite recursion

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec, left-recursion

I'm trying to write a parser for the Tiger language from *modern compiler implementation in ML*, and am stuck on one of the recursive types.

I have the following type

```
data LValue =                                                                                                                       
    Id Atom                                                                                                                         
    | RecordAccess LValue Atom                                                                                                      
    | ArraySubscript LValue Expression
```

with the following grammar:

```
lvalue -> id
       -> lvalue.id
       -> lvalue[exp]
id -> atom
exp -> (the big, overarching, everything-is-an-expression type)
```

And I'm trying to parse it with Parsec, but I'm getting stuck in an infinitely recursive loop. Here's my current base parser:

```
lvalueParser :: Parsec String () LValue                                                                                             
lvalueParser =                                                                                                                      
    try (Id <$> (atomParser <* (notFollowedBy (char '.'))))                                                                         
    <|> try recordAccessParser                                                                                                      
    where recordAccessParser = (uncurry RecordAccess) <$> do {                                                                      
      record <- lvalueParser;                                                                                                         
      char '.';                                                                                                                     
      atom <- atomParser;                                                                                                           
      return (record, atom)                                                                                                      
      }
```

(Note: I haven't yet attempted to implement anything to handle the `ArrayAccess` portion)

Clearly, the infinite-loopiness happens when the `recordAccessParser` calls back to the `lvalueParser`.

I can change the `recordAccessParser` thusly:

```
recordAccessParser = (uncurry RecordAccess) <$> do {                                                                      
          record <- atomParser;                                                                                                         
          char '.';                                                                                                                     
          atom <- atomParser;                                                                                                           
          return (Id record, atom)                                                                                                      
          }
```

and it terminates. However, it will not parse record access more than a single level deep:

```
Parsec.parse lvalueParser "" "record_1.field_1.field_2"
#=> RecordAccess (Id record_1) (Id field_1)
```

And I expect

```
#=> RecordAccess (RecordAccess (Id record_1) (Id field_1)) (Id field_2)
```

I looked at [`chainl1`](http://stuckinaninfiniteloop.blogspot.com/2011/10/left-recursion-in-parsec.html), but the type of the chaining parser is `a -> a -> a`, and that doesn't match the type of `LValue` that reflects the grammar. I also looked at [`many`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14674328); however I don't have a constant prefix for each term - the left recursion term is what I'm trying to parse into part of the result type.

I imagine I'm missing a specific concept of Parsec/parsing and would love to be pointed in the right direction. There are more types in the language that I'm writing a parser for that will have similar constructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you cannnot use `chainl1` here,
You can define `chainl1`-like combinator like this:

```
leftRec :: (Stream s m t)
        => ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m (a -> a) -> ParsecT s u m a
leftRec p op = rest =<< p
  where
    rest x = do f <- op
                rest (f x)
          <|> return x
```

I consulted [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/src/Text.Parsec.Combinator.html#chainl1) to implement this.
By using this combinator, `lvalueParser` can be defined as follows:

```
lvalueParser :: Parser LValue
lvalueParser = leftRec idParser (recordAccessModifier <|> arraySubscriptModifier)
  where
    idParser = Id <$> atomParser
    recordAccessModifier = do
      a <- char '.' *> atomParser
      return (\l -> RecordAccess l a)
    arraySubscriptModifier = do
      e <- between (char '[') (char ']') expParser
      return (\l -> ArraySubscript l e)
```

Example:

```
main = parseTest lvalueParser "x.y[2].z"
-- => RecordAccess (ArraySubscript (RecordAccess (Id 'x') 'y') (ENat 2)) 'z'
```

where `Atom`, `Expression`, and their parsers are defined as follows:

```
type Atom = Char
atomParser :: Parser Atom
atomParser = letter <?> "atom"

data Expression = ENat Int
  deriving Show
expParser :: Parser Expression
expParser = (ENat . read) <$> many digit
```

Answer (score 5):

The usual way to parse left-recursive grammars with tools that don't support left recursion, is indeed to replace the left recursion with repetition (i.e. `many`). For record access that'd mean replacing a rule like

```
lvalue ::= lvalue '.' ID
         | primaryLValue
```

with

```
lvalue ::= primaryLValue ('.' ID)*
```

In terms of Parsec that would mean:

```
record <- atomParser                                                                                                       
fields <- many (char '.' >> idParser)
```

Now you have an `LValue` and a list of 0 or more field names, which doesn't fit your AST type, but you can solve that by folding the `RecordAccess` constructor over the list.

Comment: In effect: parse first using a different grammar, and then fix the parse tree to reflect the desired grammar.